# VBA Number format of Pivot-Table's data range doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Cost()

    Dim CurrentPivot As String

    On Error GoTo OnError

    Expand

    CurrentPivot = ActiveSheet.Name

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(CurrentPivot).PivotFields("Sum of Hours"). _
        Orientation = xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(CurrentPivot).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        CurrentPivot).PivotFields("Cost"), "Sum of Cost", xlSum
    FormatProj
    Zero
    Range("B43:AJ5000").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00"

OnError:
    MsgBox ("Viewing data in $Cost")

    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
    Range("B44").Select

End Sub
```

My numbers still look like  `2615233.698`

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question to improve it. At least include explain what your code actually does and what you expect it to do (your desired result). Just posting code without asking any question at all is very bad practice.

Comment: is the `Range("B43:AJ5000")` suppose to be the `PivotTable`'s range ?

Comment: I agree with you. I should have explained more. This code just display the Dollar cost from a pivot table. and yes that is the rage where the pivot table is. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below witl format the `PivotTable`'s range to the format you wanted.

Instead of using `Range("B43:AJ5000").Select` and later `Selection`, you can directly access the Pivot-Table's range and modify it's format with:

```
PvtTbl.TableRange2.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00"
```

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Cost()

Dim CurrentPivot As String
Dim PvtTbl      As PivotTable

On Error GoTo OnError
'Expand ' <-- not sure what does this Sub-routine actually does

CurrentPivot = ActiveSheet.Name

' set the Pivot-Table object
Set PvtTbl = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(CurrentPivot)
With PvtTbl
    .PivotFields("Sum of Hours").Orientation = xlHidden
    .AddDataField .PivotFields("Cost"), "Sum of Cost", xlSum

    'FormatProj ' <-- not sure what does this Sub-routine actually does
    'Zero ' <-- not sure what does this Sub-routine actually does

    .TableRange2.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00;[Red]$#,##0.00"
End With

OnError:
MsgBox "Viewing data in $Cost"

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
Range("B44").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This Perfect. FormatProj and Zero were seperate codes for formatting the numbers/colors etc.

Comment: @user3860954 you're welcome, please mark as "ANSWER" by clicking the gray check-mark next to my answer (it will turn green) and you earn +2 points

Answer (score 0):

Define name PivotTable

```
Set tbl = wkstbl.PivotTables("ResumoEstados")
    
    With tbl
        teste = wks.Name & "!" & rngDinamica.CurrentRegion.Address
        .ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        teste, Version:=6)
        .RefreshTable
  'work with .databodyrange of the pivottable choice      
With .DataBodyRange
            .Cells.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
        End With
    End With
```